# Tracking and Updating Elements With JS

Tags: javascript, dom

Having a hard time solving this. I've used TinyMCE to create a WYSIWYG editor so that staff can copy/paste from Word into this program to check for errors (ie multiple h1 headers).

The problem I am having is once they've corrected a highlighted error. How do I remove their the set attribute or style from this element?  Here is my JS so far that does the check and creates a log. I am assuming I'll need to use the MutationObserver? I've never used it, and couldn't see to find a good explanation of it.

```
function styleGuide(){

    var searchInput = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    document.getElementById('findAllErrors').innerHTML = searchInput;

    var resultsLog = document.getElementById('passFailLog');

    // search for h1
    var h1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
    var i = 0;
    do {
        if(h1.length == 0){
            resultsLog.innerHTML = "<br /><span class='warning'>You do not have an H1 element.</span>";
        }
        else if(h1.length > 1){
            resultsLog.innerHTML = "<br /><span class='error'>You have more than one H1 element.</span>";
        }
        else {
            resultsLog.innerHTML = "<br /><span class='pass'>You have the correct amount of H1 headers.</span>";
        }
        //set style for errors
        if(i > 0){
            h1[i].style.color = "Red";
            h1[i].setAttribute("class", "fixIt");
        }
        i++;
    }
    while (i < h1.length);

    //Update Error Found to Original Editor
    var outputUpdate = document.getElementById('findAllErrors').innerHTML;
    var mceContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    var errorsFound = outputUpdate.replace(mceContent, outputUpdate);
    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(errorsFound);
}
```

Comment: Word doesn't have spellchecking?

Comment: Goes beyond spelling. Its basically preparing a document to meet a predetermined style guide and help editors format it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start of your function should reset/remove any previously set errors (removing the `Red` color and removing the `fixIt` class).

Then the function can perform its checking operation and re-apply errors if needed.

This lets you simply call the same function each time a user makes a change.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried something like that, but with no success

` var all = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
 var i = all.length;
 var j, is_hidden;

 var attr = [
  'class',
     'style',
 ];

 var attr_len = attr.length;
 while (i--) {
     j = attr_len;

  while (j--) {
      all[i].removeAttribute(attr[j]);
  }
 }
`